# python scrapy spider: pass additional information in parse() method for each start_url

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am writing a scrapy spider in which I would like to pass additional information in `parse()` method for each `start_url`.

I have created a map from the list `start_urls` to `additional_data` and I am using that map inside the method.

```
class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['alldomain.com']
    start_urls = ['http://a.com/', 'http://b.com/', 'http://c.com/']
    additional_data = [x,y,z]
    dict_map = dict(zip(start_urls, additional_data))

    def parse(self, response):
        url_first_additional_data = dict_map[response.url]
        # do other processing
```

Is there any other better approach of doing the same thing, I am not sure whether the response.url would also have the request url and the map can eat up lots of memory if I have huge additional_data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass additional arguments to parse function you can do it by overriding default start requests method. You should rename your `start_urls` in your init method to something else if you want to use `start_requests` method, as i am renaming it to  `starting_urls`

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.starting_urls:
        yield Request(
            url,
            cb_kwargs={'additional_argument': dict_map[url]}
        )

def parse(self, response, additional_argument):
    # Here you can use that additional_argument
    pass
```

Also for getting url in parse, Response object also has the original request object in it. So you can get the request url by `response.request.url`

```
def parse(self, response):
    additional_argument = self.dict_map[response.request.url]
```

**Note that I am renaming starting_url to start_urls**